# Attribute [livewire] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am having trouble to run my code on Laravel 8 routing with laravel-livewire.
The class is within `Livewire\LandingPage`.

The error I'm getting is

> Attribute [livewire] does not exist

Here are my routes

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::livewire('/' , 'LandingPage');

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->name('dashboard');
```

Comment: what is the error you are facing ? please add the error log here

Answer (score 35):

If you are using a recent install of Laravel 8, you will have Livewire V2. In this version, [`Route::livewire()`has been removed](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading#route-livewire). Instead, you specify a normal `get()` route, with the action being the Livewire component class.

```php
Route::get('/' , App\Http\Livewire\LandingPage::class);
```

Comment: Another perfectly good question closed on SO... remember to swap `@yield('content')` with `{{ $slot }}` in your `app.blade.php` also for the conversion to V2.

Comment: Aye, its not a question that should have been closed. I have asked to reopen it. That said, you can use either the `yield`/`section` as before, or slots. Depends if you are using partials or components; they're different things to achieve the same goal.

Comment: in laravel 8 yield/section didn't work for me.

Comment: Although that's not related to this question, read the upgrade-manual at https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading

Answer (score 8):

If you use livewire v1.x please use this annotation :

```
//(livewire v1.x)
Route::livewire('/post', 'LandingPage');
```

If you are using livewire v2.0 please use this one :

```
//(livewire v2.x)
Route::get('/post', \App\Http\Livewire\LandingPage::class);
```

Comment: Thank you stic-lab this still works on Laravel 2.5

Answer (score 0):

From the error it appears you do not have the auth system setup:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // Only with LiveWire v1
    //Route::livewire('/blog', 'blog')->section('blog');

    // For LiveWire 2.
    Route::get('/blog' , 'BlogController@index');
});
```

You are calling the `auth` middleware and the error is stating there is no LoginController presently located in `Auth\LoginController`

Do you have any auth scaffolding setup?

Didn't realize this was such an old thread.

Answer (score -2):

With Laravel 8.29 and LiveWire 2.4.0

> UnexpectedValueException
> Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Livewire\Blog].

I think that is better tha you need create a new Controller in App\Http\Controllers and link the route with this Controller. In the view use @liveware to your LiveWire Controller.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // Only with LiveWire v1
    //Route::livewire('/blog', 'blog')->section('blog');

    // For LiveWire 2.
    Route::get('/blog' , 'BlogController@index');
});
```

App\Http\Controllers\BlogController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('blog.index');
    }
}
```

resources/views/blog/index.blade.php

```
@livewire('blog')
```

**Note:**
With the fix (https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading)

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
        ->namespace($this->namespace) // Remove me
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

you will have problems with routes in Middlewares

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [Auth\LoginController] does not exist.